# How to use DbContext for EntityDatasource in EF 6.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, entitydatasource

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application which uses .NET framework v4.5 and EF v6.1.1.

I am using new [EntityDatasource](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource/) control for binding and updating the <asp:FormView />. Previously, I was using the `ObjectContext` and now I changed it to use `DbContext`. After this change I got build errors due to invalid type cast:

```
e.Context = new SchoolEntities();
```

This is obvious as the **"Context"** property of the EntityDatasource EventArgs `e` is of type `ObjectContext` while *SchoolEntities* of type `DbContext`.

I'm also doing some CRUD operation using the `e.Context` property e.g:

```
var school = e.Context.Schools.FirstOrDefault();
e.Context.Departments.Add(...);
e.Context.SaveChanges();
```

To fix the error I got the ObjectContext from the DbContext as follows:

```
e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;
```

Here `e` is Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource's event args.

Also I have added the **EntityDataSource_ContextCreating()** event to solve the type casting problem:

```
protected void EntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_ctx == null)
        _ctx = new SchoolEntities();
    e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;
}
```

After doing this change, I got rid of the build errors but it caused several other errors.

### Problems

1. If I'm using **e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;** then when getting the entity back(`var school = (School)e.Entity;`) in the EntityDatasource' updating event I'm losing the navigation properties.
2. I'm not finding any way how I can avoid the use of ObjectContext in EntityDatasource. I want to stay away from ObjectContext as it is completely removed in EF 7.

### What I have tried

So to resolve all these problems, I currently added a page level context object like:

```
private SchooEntities _ctx;
```

I removed **e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;** from the EntityDatasource's context creating event. I also removed the existing codes which was using the **e.Context** property for doing the CRUD operations. I used the page level context(_ctx) variable instead of e.Context and everything worked fine. So this confirms the culprit is **e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_ctx).ObjectContext;**

### Questions

1. How effectively use `DbContext` with the EntityDatasource (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource/) control?
2. For my case, what changes I will do in order to get back the navigation properties(while retrieving the entity back from the eventargs`var school = (School)e.Entity;`)?
3. If I will not use the `e.Context` property of the EntityDataSource control then I think there is NO use of EntityDatasource at all? (FYI: I'm using the EntityDatasource control only for **Bind** and **Update** operations)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the navigation properties are filled, you need to set those you want populated as a comma separated list in the EntityDataSource's [Include] property.